# Should I use a <form> or just a <div> to create a form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using React JS with Apollo client, when I want to create like a registration form for example, I usually create a div which contains some input fields and a button, the button is not of type "submit" it is just a regular button with an "onClick()" event that runs the registration function ... it does the job and I like the way the registration logic runs without passing any data through the URL as well as it doesn't need to refresh the page after each registration approach.

So the question is which way is better ?

1. Using a form tag to do form things
2. Using a div instead

NOTE: I know that there is some packages that can handle these situations like "Formik" for example ... but I like to code everything my self.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, it's always better to keep using semantic HTML tag e.g `<form>` for form.

There are some advantages using `<form`> from what I've known so far:

1. Support CSS pseudoclass `:invalid` and `:valid` which may be handy
2. Better accessibility

> Note: Using the  element will automatically communicate a section of content as a form landmark, if it is provided an accessible name. Developers should always prefer using the correct semantic HTML element over using ARIA.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/form_role#description

For CSS pseudoclass demo, you could check my [Stackblitz](https://web-platform-3qgku3.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `<form>` and make your `<button>` of `type="submit"`.

Instead of adding an EventHandler to the button on `onClick`, I would bind it to the `onSubmit` event of the form.

With `event.preventDefault()` you stop the submission of the form and you can handle your registration logic there.